# How to keep my vb.net program relatively secure

Tags: vb.net, reverse-engineering

I wrote a small program in vb.net and I'm looking for a simple way to keep people from just copying the executable and running it on another machine for reverse engineering without the installer. I understand that if people want the program bad enough they will figure out a way to get a hold of it, I'm basically just looking for some kind of deterrent to keep our competitors from walking around and copying it.

Comment: `How to keep my program relatively secure`  dont release it.  One way to slow down reverse engineering is to Obfuscate the assembly.  It makes the decompiled code hard to read and follow. All the methods get renamed `_i` or `jjj`  Protecting against copying the EXE is something else

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559141/the-right-way-to-activate-and-monitor-software-license-through-online-checking

Comment: `I just don't want our competitors walking by and trying to copy it`  you should update the post with details like this.  The post as is, is pretty broad and sounds like you want to protect your MineCraft launcher

Comment: ...where does this thing run? on your company machines or is industrial software which is sold?  Do you have internet access to them?  Licensing is not trivial and there are many models.  You arent giving anyone much to work with.

Comment: This is industrial software which is going to be sold. There is internet access on the machines

Answer (score 0):

Logan,

The bad news is that you cannot stop people from reverse engineering your desktop application.  You have 2 options:

1. Create a web application instead.  The code will run securely on your server.
2. Use Remote Desktop Services.  This way you can install your program on your server and let the users use it via RDS.  Here is an article that illustrates the concept and how to implement it on Microsoft Azure: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx

Comment: Could I do something like hiding some file in a folder somewhere when the installer runs and make the program check for the file, then obfuscate the executable like Plutonix mentioned? The people that would want this program aren't going to be able to spend a bunch of time trying to get it, they're most likely going to just kind of walk by and try to copy it real quick to take home and reverse engineer. The program runs in a factory setting on dedicated machines to monitor temperature, I just don't want our competitors walking by and trying to copy it.

Comment: Sure, you can come up with your own elaborate scheme how to hide files, but the fact remains that if the users have the executable in their hands, they can reverse engineer it and steal you code.

Comment: One thing to consider is the time spent vs potential benefits.  If you make it hard enough via obfuscation that it is not worth for the user to spend the time to reverse engineer it, they probably won't.  However, strictly from technical stand point you cannot protect the executable.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into the two options that you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Makes you wonder, what is your competitor doing on your factory floor? Trying to secure your application in a factory where a competitor can freely roam around is like bolting your back door shut and leaving the front door open with a note to tell burglars where you keep your piggy bank.

Comment: Are your competitors so clueless they can't write a simple temperature monitor?  If so, I doubt you have anything to worry about on the reverse engineering front. If they are not completely brain dead, then who cares.  I know it would take *me* longer to reverse engineer a temp monitor than to write it from scratch.

Answer (score -2):

The standard approach is to create a license key that will only work on a specific machine and store it in the registry. This can be something as simple as:

1. When your app starts get a unique machine id (http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/181408-get-unique-machine-ids/)
2. Perform a one way hash on it
3. See if this value is stored in the registry
4. If it isn't, display a dialog displaying the unique machine id and asking for the 'license'
5. Accept input of the license so they don't need to ask again

You can manually calculate the one way hash yourself for computers that you want to run the software on.

This won't stop a determined hacker but it'll keep the 99.9% of people who can't hack your software honest.